# Resources for native Metro app development with Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Are there resources on the web which help to get started with **native [Metro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_%28design_language%29) app development** with **Delphi** (Win32)?

So far I found the MSDN introduction, **[Getting started with Metro style apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211386.aspx)**, which links to the available API sets, including two native APIs:

- **[Windows Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx)** ([WinRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime)) - "A native API built into the operating system.
  Fundamental to Metro style apps. Implemented in C++ and supported in
  JavaScript, C#, Visual Basic, and C++ in a way that feels natural for
  each language".
- **[Win32 and COM for Metro style apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx)** - "The subset of the Win32
  and COM APIs that you can use in a Metro style app". Quote:

> Metro style apps can use a subset of the Win32 and COM API. This
>   subset of APIs was chosen to support key scenarios for Metro style
>   apps that were not already covered by the Windows Runtime, HTML/CSS,
>   or other supported languages or standards. The Windows App
>   Certification Kit ensures that your app uses only this subset of the
>   Win32 and COM API.

---

Side note: the first **Metro app contest** already [closed on January 8, 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2011/12/07/get-your-app-in-the-store-on-opening-day.aspx) according to the Metro [Windows Store](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/) blog and the winners have been [introduced](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/02/29/introducing-the-winners-of-the-first-apps-contest.aspx) end of February - these Metro apps are already available through the [Windows 8 Consumer Preview](http://preview.windows.com/).

Comment: There isn't even a version of Delphi that supports WinRT (either native or managed) yet. Sure, you can do it by treating WinRT as a COM-based API which it ultimately is (e.g. see http://www.thomgerdes.com/2011/12/writing-hello-world-for-winrt-in-delphi.html), but don't expect any serious support or documentation until it's properly supported by Embarcadero.

Comment: Here's hoping that the accepted answer in late-2012 becomes "Use Delphi XE3, now with native Metro support".

Comment: I'm also hoping that metro apps submissions to Windows Store will not be restricted to apps created by Visual Studio only.

Comment: It would be nice if more users deny any platform that has only vendor-locked compilers. Unfortunatelly, lots of them don't care. Betrayers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some new blog and forum articles around this topic, pointing to problems with API usage which disqualifies applications from the MS app store:

[**Why no native WinRT support in Delphi XE3?**](http://delphitools.info/2012/08/23/why-no-native-winrt-support-in-delphi-xe3/) - quoting a [forum post by Allen Bauer](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=484319#484319)

> We are very keen on supporting WinRT with native Delphi & C++ code.
>   Right now, the issues surrounding the WinRT space center around the
>   fact that many OS-supplied APIs which are required by anyone
>   implementing their own language RTL are actually off-limits unless
>   you’re the VC++ RTL DLL. You know, little things like RtlUnwind for
>   exception processing and VirtualAlloc (et. al.) for memory management…
>   Any calls to those APIs from your application will automatically
>   disqualify your application from being an "official" WinRT application
>   capable of delivering through the MS app store.

See also: 
[**Third-party compilers locked out of Windows Runtime development**](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/6347-third-party-compilers-locked-out-of-windows-runtime-development.html)

On the other hand, this [official Microsoft presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Lang-NEXT/Lang-NEXT-2012/The-Windows-Runtime) contains a statement that

> Martyn (Lovell) made it clear that we not only want language designers and
>   implementers to add WinRT to their list of target platforms for their
>   language and toolchains, but we will help and advise.

Answer (score 14):

Thom Gerdes wrote this blog article on December 14, 2011:

**[Writing Hello World for WinRT in Delphi](http://www.thomgerdes.com/2011/12/writing-hello-world-for-winrt-in-delphi.html)**

> There is relatively little information out there on developing Native
>   Metro applications, especially for languages other than those that
>   Microsoft has provided projections for (C++, C#, and JavaScript).
>   Other languages, including Delphi, need to create their own
>   projections before they can use them effectively. I've been
>   investigating getting Delphi to produce native applications for WinRT.

And his article **[Hello World: Hooking events](http://www.thomgerdes.com/2011/12/hello-world-hooking-events.html)** shows how to use Metro "multicast delegate" event handlers with Delphi.

Sources are available at https://github.com/tgerdes/DelphiWinRT