# Anything yet on writing an App in Delphi XE2 to utilize new additions in Windows 8?

Tags: delphi, api, delphi-xe2, windows-8, windows-runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources for native Metro app development with Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653260/resources-for-native-metro-app-development-with-delphi)

I've been searching for anything about how to utilize the new additions in Windows 8 in a Delphi XE2 application. Although I know there's the new WinRT API, there has to be some resource of how to actually use it in Windows 8. It should be simple things, like how to customize how the start menu tile shows, etc. I'm sure someone's already taken the time to figure these things out, and I'm trying to find it. The best I could find is [This](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/10/delphi-xamlmetro-app-for-windows-8-by-thom-gerdes/), but no source code.

Any leads on this? I just need some guidelines to using the WinRT API for Windows 8 in Delphi XE2.

Comment: The source of the Thom Gerdes Delphi XE2 Metro Demo App is located here https://github.com/tgerdes/DelphiWinRT

Comment: And [`here's`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653260/resources-for-native-metro-app-development-with-delphi) the question asking for the similar.

Comment: OK I understand the vote to close due to duplicate, but why the downvote?

Comment: I don't downvote on duplicates. SOmebody else is being a goof. Upvote for you. :-)

Comment: It's not a "Possible Duplicate", it is an "Exact Duplicate"...

Comment: I have observed that there seems to a sinister presence on SO that is downvoting all Delphi related questions.  I don't think there is any way for users to find out who it is as down/up votes are anon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi XE2 pre-dates Windows 8 as you know. Windows 8 is not even finalised and the new WinRT is radically different from Win32. There is no support for WinRT in XE2.

Anyone who is using Delphi to create WinRT apps is doing an awful lot of low level hacking. This is not a viable long term approach. Any code you may be able to produce this way will surely be thrown away when proper Delphi tooling arrives. So, in my view, you will have to wait for official Delphi support, or use the MS tools.

Comment: I do know this, of course it won't be "supported" yet, but things are still possible. Technically, you can build a Windows 8 app in Delphi 1 if you wanted, although it would be a nightmare. In my link above, it's already been experimented with, but no source code.

Comment: @Jerry I was just browsing the source code. And no you can't build a Windows 8 app in Delphi 1 since that only produces 16 bit outputs.

Comment: Ok I was wrong there but I hope the point is understood.

Comment: The point is that winrt in today's delphi would be a dead end. Use ms tools instead.

Comment: Why do you call it hacking? Isnt WinRT and Metro just com?

Comment: @Remko Well, COM is underneath, but you don't see any COM when you drive WinRT from the MS tools. The idea is to shield the programmer from that. I can't imagine Embarcadero presenting raw COM interfaces when they support WinRT. But there's lots of speculation in there. Which is why I would not attempt to build anything serious on WinRT with Delphi yet. If you are going to write dead end code you may as well do it with the least effort which right now is MS tools since they support WinRT out of the box.

Comment: @David Heffernan: OK, fair enough.